# How can I sound-trigger a Nikon Z50 camera?

Tags: triggers, sound, nikon-z50

The Nikon Z 50 has no analog trigger, only the [ML-L7](https://www.nikon.nl/nl_NL/product/accessories/coolpix/coolpix-connectivity/bluetooth-remote-control-ml-l7), a bluetooth one.

I'm not sure what is the delay between said trigger and the photo (it cannot be too fast, there's Bluetooth in between), but in any case it has no external analog input.

I would like to trigger the Z 50 using sound (bursting balloons, or small explosions) so I'm looking for a way to use sound. For balloons of course I could trigger a flash with a long exposure on the camera, but small explosions don't work with flashes, so I really need an audio trigger.

What are my options?

Comment: You have an additional latency issue with sound - it travels at about 1 foot/ms, 5 seconds/mile roughly. As the sound from a bursting balloon is due to the rubber travelling at faster than the speed of sound, the action will be over before the sound itself reaches the trigger. For fireworks, of course, you are dealing with much greater distances, therefore even higher latency.

Comment: @Tetsujin your analysis is correct and I also didn't think about it, but I have a flammable gas inside the balloon, I am interested in the flame actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bluetooth connection is far too slow for any high speed triggering use, and I'm not aware of any audio trigger that has bluetooth capability.

There is no other option for the Z50. If you must have audio triggering of the shutter, I think you would be better off getting a different camera.

Your only real option is a remote trigger for the flashes; something like the [**Miops Smart+**](https://www.miops.com/products/smart) will give you multiple options for triggering the flash (audio/laser/etc); the laser might work for some things like small explosions, and they also have a water drop add-on for it as well. For things like fire/fireworks/lightning, the subject itself acts more like flash combined with a long duration shutter/exposure.

Comment: "MIOPS Smart+ Camera Trigger is compatible with the DSLR and mirrorless cameras of most major brands like Canon, Nikon,
Sony, FujiFilm, etc. The camera must have a shutter release port to be triggered by MIOPS." *No analog port on a Z50 Z30 or Zfc, as the OP already mentioned.*

Comment: And no use when flashes are not suitable, like fire. Maybe I have to build/buy a mechanical shutter to place in front of the lens

Comment: @Tetsujin, that's why I specifically said "for triggering flash."

Comment: @FarO, you would also have to make an electronic control for the mechanical shutter that can interface with an audio trigger. And that mechanical shutter would have to have fast enough travel time to freeze the motion; neither of those things are simple. If you really must have shutter control then I think you would be better off getting a different camera. For things like fire/fireworks/lightning, the subject itself acts more like flash with a long duration shutter/exposure.

Comment: Potentially I could do the opposite and link the bluetooth trigger to the flame trigger with a delay, not to use the sound but to control the event causing it, but it's not related to this question of course.

Answer (score 0):

z50 is useless on matter of triggers .. even the archeological d3100 has compatible triggers for baloon popping , lightning  like PLUTO trigger.. z50 has nothing of that compatible as far as i know.